# Laravek 5.3, Many to Many, Как сохранить данные в базу

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel

Здравствуйте.
Я только учу php и заодно сразу laravel. Пишу небольшой проект, не коммерческий, а для обучения.

Есть пост и есть типы поста.
Каждый пост может иметь несколько типов и каждый тип может быть назначен разным постам.
Я реализовал отношение многие ко многим

Наверное важно. Типы, их количество и имена фиксированы, за ранее известны.
Типы я уже внес в базу.

Я создал форму добавления поста. В форме помимо полей поста есть чекбоксы с типами.

```
@foreach ($postTypes as $type)
    <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
        <input name="type[{{$type->id}}]" type="checkbox" id="{{ $type['name'] }}" value="{{ $type['name'] }}"> {{ $type['name'] }}
    </label>
@endforeach
```

На выходе я получаю массив:

```
    "type" => array:4 [▼
        0 => "fan"
        1 => "edu"
        2 => "news"
        3 => "review"
]
```

Как это правильно сохранить?
Я немного в ступоре, нагуглил много всего и немного запутался, потерялся или растерялся...

Буду благодарен если тыкните носом в каком направлении гуглить.

Comment: Сам нашел ответ:

Comment: Не знаю правильно или нет, но работает:
foreach ($request['type'] as $typeId => $typeName) {
            $newPost->types()->attach($typeId);
        }

Comment: В целом да, правильно использовать attach https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Comment: Ссылки хоть и не очень приветствуются, но все же, почитай http://eloquentbyexample.com/

Comment: @Orange_shadow Спасибо, ссылка хорошая.